# Remove tag with a specific attr from text PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a span tag that has role attr button. What I want to achieve is to remove the whole span while matching not the span itself but the role attribute

```
$str = 'This is a test buton. <span id="UmniBooking_36" class="insideB" type="Form" style="cursor: pointer;color:" role="button" >Click here</span>';
$str = preg_replace('~<role="button"(.*?)</(.*?)>~Usi', "", $str);
```

I am doing something wrong but I cant figure out what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is not recommended for manipulating parsable HTML.  DOMDocument can hand this task with intuitive, reliable native method calls.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/0BO3l))

```
$html = <<<HTML
This is a test buton. <span id="UmniBooking_36" class="insideB" type="Form" style="cursor: pointer;color:" role="button" >Click here</span>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('span') as $span) {
    if ($span->getAttribute('role') === 'button') {
        $parent = $span->parentNode;
        $parent->removeChild($span);
        $parent->nodeValue = trim($parent->nodeValue);
    }
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Output (creates valid HTML with a parent tag):

```
<p>This is a test buton.</p>
```

Comment: Why it is not recommended?

Comment: Because regex is "DOM-ignorant" -- it merely makes decisions based on characters that "look like HTML" rather than more intelligently respecting HTML.  It doesn't get tricked by minor changes in quoting (single versus double), it won't be fooled by `data-role` when searching for `role` attributes, and DOM parsing libraries have a more intuitive/self-documenting syntax. Patterns can be unintentionally weak and fooled by sneaky users who seek vulnerabilities. https://3v4l.org/g9SRK

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that I forgot to add `(.*?)` before the role attr

```
$str = preg_replace('~<(.*?)role="button"(.*?)</(.*?)>~Usi', "", $str);
```

That way it works fine.